# Why do gimballed gyroscopes platforms need drive motors in order to maintain it's fixed orientation?

Tags: instrumentation

I have a fundamental misunderstanding about the role of gimbals and gyroscopes in determination of angular rotation rates (in inertial measurement units). A set of three gimbals enables an object mounted on it's innermost gimbal to assume an arbitart orientation in space. Viewed differently, a three axis gimbals set enables full freedom (3 degrees of freedom) of relative motion between the object mounted on them and it's support, what paves the way for the design of stabilized platforms.

In particular, one can mount three orthogonal gyroscopes on a gimballed stabilized platform, so that the gimbals isolate the gyros from any external torques and the three gyros will maintain a fixed orientation relative to the inertial space.

Up to this point, i agree with the chains of reasoning. What i don't understand is why one can't simply incorporate angle sensors in order to measure the angles between the axes of the gyros and spacecraft axes?

I now quote the wikipedia article on "gimbal":

> In inertial navigation, as applied to ships and submarines, a minimum of three gimbals are needed to allow an inertial navigation system (stable table) to remain fixed in inertial space, compensating for changes in the ship's yaw, pitch, and roll. In this application, the inertial measurement unit (IMU) is equipped with three orthogonally mounted gyros to sense rotation about all axes in three-dimensional space. The gyro outputs are kept to a null through drive motors on each gimbal axis, to maintain the orientation of the IMU. To accomplish this, the gyro error signals are passed through "resolvers" mounted on the three gimbals, roll, pitch and yaw. These resolvers perform an automatic matrix transformation according to each gimbal angle, so that the required torques are delivered to the appropriate gimbal axis. The yaw torques must be resolved by roll and pitch transformations. The gimbal angle is never measured. Similar sensing platforms are used on aircraft.

So if the initial purpose of the stabilizes gimballed platform was to isolate the gyros from any external torques, why do we now need a complicated drive motors system and a matrix calculator in order to apply torques to the components of this platform?

My question might result from a lack of knowledge on practical engineering issues, or maybe from a basic misunderstanding of the mechanics involved here. Anyway, my attempts at reading other sources than wikipedia didn't help me a lot, so i'll be glad to get an exhaustive answer.

Comment: The gyros are tiny and play no direct role is maintaining the orientation of the platform (they aren't flywheels). Some are just laser beams. So all they do is sense a change. These sense signals are processed and the gimbals stepped to null the changes.

Comment: @Phil - you should post this as an answer so that it canbe voted ...

Answer (score 1):

You asked "why all this complexity, why not to simply measure the rotation angles of the mounting axles of the stabilized plate and let the gyros keep it stable"! The gyros cannot keep it stable due the friction. The motors are there to compensate that friction. But to be able to give just the right amount of help the motors need a controller. The rotation angle sensors in the mounting axles of the plate are still needed to tell how much the vehicle has rotated around the stabilized plate.

So: The motors adjust the rotation angles of the stabilized plate in relative to the rotations of the vehicle. The goal is to keep the absolute position of the plate constant, no matter how the vehicle happens to rotate.

The mechanical gyros are used to show any attempts to change the directions of their rotation axles. It can be detected for ex. from the bending of the axles. As soon as some bending is detected the motor controller let the motors rotate so that the absolute directions of the gyro axles do not get changed.

If the plate tries to rotate (along the vehicle) just so that the direction of a qyro axis does not change, it still could be in theory detected from the change of the gyro rotation rate but slow tilting, say a degree in a minute is undetectable as the change of gyro rotation rate tens of thousands of revolutions per a minute. 3 perpedicular gyros fix that problem and generally give relatively easily usable data of the vehicle rotations.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix calculator sounds fancy, untill you realize that this is one of the earliest things engineers learn in uni and is realy just a way of avoid using sinus and cosinus ad nauseum*. A control system needs to be present  ayway and the computations needed arent really all that hard, they just sound fancy.

Now the gimbal system has  a nasty problem. If you turn it to a certain orientation it  ceases  to work. Since the disks need to be fed with energy anyway or they would cease to eventually rotating. You would need motors anyway to counteract  friction. But you can actually read the energy changes and keep the gyro in base position. This then will never end up having to deal diminished degrees of freedom leading eventually  to gimbval lock.

In a way this is technically simpler the letting the gimbal free float and reading  angles. Even if you were to read angles directly im not sure you could or even would want  to skip the matrix calculator.

* Although, most students dont realize it at this point that engineering math is not about doing computations like in earlier school stages. So freshmen tend to learn abhor matrices since they are superficially labour intensive. Not realizing yet that labour intensive is way better than hard or complicated (which is what they equate labour intensive with). Labour intensive just simply means can be done by a machine. This frees you to think on higher order things. But then freshmen arent engineers, yet.

Oh and also its numerically more stable.